# Why am I getting this type error: instance vs prototype

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototype, instance

Hi I am trying to learn the difference, or what is happening between .prototype and just a regular instance. Can anyone explain it, and why isnt this code working? I get a type error: "undefined is not a function". I am just trying to see what happens between the Ninja() class and .prototype, and the first instance. Then I'm trying to see what happens when I make a new Ninja() class called ninja. And repeat

```
     function Ninja() {
     this.swingSword = function() {
     return true;
     };
     }

     Ninja.prototype.swingSword = function() {
     return false;
     };

    var ninja = new Ninja;
    console.log(Ninja.prototype.swingSword());
    console.log(Ninja.swingSword());
    console.log(ninja.swingSword());
    console.log(ninja.prototype.swingSword());
```

Answer (score 0):

`prototype` is a property of `Function` object and as all the function objects inherit from `Function`, they all have that property. In your case, `Ninja` is a function, but `ninja` is just an object constructed by `Ninja`, so it doesn't have `prototype`. Since, it doesn't have `prototype`, JavaScript returns with `undefined`. And you are trying to call `swingSword` on `undefined`, which is not possible. That is why you are getting that error.

You can check that like this

```
console.log({}.toString.call(Ninja));
# [object Function]
console.log({}.toString.call(ninja));
# [object Object]
console.log(Ninja.prototype);
# { swingSword: [Function] }
console.log(ninja.prototype);
# undefined
```

Also, note that, you have defined `swingSword` only on `Ninja.prototype` not on `Ninja`. When you invoke `Ninja.swingSowrd()`, JavaScript will look for it in `Ninja` first and then in its parent's prototype which would be `Function.prototype`. Lookups on `Ninja` will not involve `Ninja.prototype`. That is you are getting an error on that line as well.

Comment: Okay. then why did Ninja.swingSword() not work in the console?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `Ninja.swingSword();` because the function is not defined before the `Ninja()` constructor/function is called.
But you could do `new Ninja.swingSword();` returning `true`.

That said, `ninja.prototype` is undefined because it's an instance of the `Ninja` class, and all `prototype` variables are assigned directly to `ninja`. But, upon construction, you're setting `this.swingSword` to a new function that returns `true`. That's why `ninja.swingSword();` will return `true`, instead of `false` as you might expect through the prototype function.

Answer (score 0):

The function Ninja does not have a swingSword method, the Ninja.prototype does. A function is an object same as many other objects with the difference that you can create instances with it using the new keyword and that it has a build in prototype member.

If I have an object called ben like this:

```
var ben = {
  name:"Ben",
  address:{
    street:"street name",
    city:"city name"
  }
}
```

It should be quite obvious here that I don't have ben.street but do have a ben.address.street.

An explanation about constructor functions and prototype can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).